# Jbutton positioning inside a tabbed pane

Tags: java, jbutton, jtabbedpane

I am currently working on making a digital school planner and want to use multiple JButtons inside a JTabbedPane. But I am currently having a problem where even one button takes up the whole pane and would like a solution to this.

I have created a test program that mirrors how i am coding my main program:

```
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class tabTest extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5101892517858668104L;
    private JFrame frame;
    private int WIDTH = 450;
    private int HEIGHT = 600;

    private JTabbedPane tab;

    public tabTest() {

        frame = new JFrame();
        // frame.setUndecorated(true);
        /****************************************************
         * Set up frame
         *****************************************************/
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setLocation(50, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        /******************************************************
         * Set up Tabbed pane and buttons
         ******************************************************/
        tab = new JTabbedPane();
        tab.setBounds(20, 50, 400, 500);
        tab.setBackground(Color.white);
        tab.setFocusable(false);

        JButton tabButton1 = new JButton("test");

        tab.addTab("Week 1", tabButton1);
        tab.addTab("Week 2", null);
        tab.addTab("Week 3", null);
        tab.addTab("Week 4", null);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tab);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new tabTest();

    }
}
```

i have tried using `BorderLayout.POSITION` and it chucked up error after error any alternate solution would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tabbedPane can only hold one "object". If you add a button, your pane is full. However you can add a container with more room to the pane. For example a *JPanel*. The JPanel can now hold as many "objects" as you want and can use it's own LayoutManager.

```
JPanel moreButtons = new JPanel();
moreButtons.add(new JButton("test1"));
moreButtons.add(new JButton("test2"));
moreButtons.add(new JButton("test3"));
moreButtons.add(new JButton("test4"));

tab.addTab("Week 1", moreButtons);
```

Also you crete and initialize your whole GUI inside the constructor. It might be cleaner to define a second methode like `initializeGUI()` to seperate the creation of the object and the initilazation of your GUI. Also you should seperate the GUI-thread and the Main-thread, by using `invokeLater`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    Gui g = new Gui();
    g.initalizeGUI();
    Gui.setVisible(true);
  }
  });
}
```

There is no need to extend JFrame and to create a seperate JFrame inside your JFrame. Remove the `extends JFrame` or the creation of your JFrame inside the class. You can access the JFrame mehtodes from inside your extended class.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

public MyFrame () {
    /**
     * Set up frame 
     */
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setLocation(50, 50);
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. how would i add an action listener to these JButtons?

Answer (score 0):

Add another container like `JPanel` inside your `JTabbedPane` like this:

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());   // you can change layout according to your need.
    p.add(tabButton1);
    tab.addTab("Week 1", panel);
    tab.addTab("Week 2", null);
    tab.addTab("Week 3", null);
    tab.addTab("Week 4", null);
```

Add all your components to the `JPanel` that you want to show on the tabs.